# Smooth scrolling not working with Magic Mouse and macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Tags: mouse, macos

Recently, smooth scrolling has stopped working on my MacBook Pro when scrolling with the Magic Mouse. Using the internal trackpad works fine and smooth scrolling behaves correctly.

I initially noticed this behavior in Chrome but it appears to affect all apps, including native ones like Pages or Safari.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by deleting the mouse from Bluetooth settings, and then pairing it again using a lightning cable.